How can Python place packages with high memory usage on shared memory for other Python programs to import？
How can Python place packages with high memory usage on shared memory for other Python programs to import, thereby reducing memory usage in multi process scenarios?

Please show the code you're struggling with Minimal Reproducible Example

you can import SharedMemory from multiprocessing library (Python>3.8) but without a better definition of the problem I can't say anything more.
